# How to convert part of a char array into an NSString*?

Tags: ios, nsstring, cstring

```
char arr[] = "abcdefg";
// I know I can do this
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:arr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If I want to convert part of the `arr` array into an NSString*? say `cde` rather then the whole string `abcdefg`? How do I achieve that?

Comment: maybe use initWithUTF8String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:arr + 2
    length:3 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thank you @rob, It worked! But it is strange that there's no method like `initWithBytes:(const char*)buffer index:(int)i length:(int)l encoding:(NSStringEncoding)e`.

Comment: You could always write a category.